# How to show a website as a wallpaper in Windows 10?

Tags: web, background, desktop, wallpaper

is there a way to show a webpage on the windows 10 desktop (as a wallpaper, not in the browser)? I'd like to show an URL to google calendar on the background.

I have no idea to get this done. (Is it configurable? Is there a solution in Python 3, c# or elsewhat?)

merlinuwe

Comment: (off-topic) This question reminds me of the ancient [Active Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Desktop)...

Comment: Yes, so it is. In Linux Mint there is such a tool for the desktop available: https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/desklets/view/35

Comment: It seems there are no official solution, but some 3rd party software did this, I found some of them by Googling "Windows10 active desktop".

Answer (score 3):

the easy solution:

Install this:  http://www.stefanbion.de/htmlwindow/

and add a link to the desktop with this target:

```
C:\HtmlWindow\HtmlWindow.exe "Kalender" "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r" 3600
```

---

The not so easy solution:

Install selenium: `pip install selenium`

Download the geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
and put it somewhere in your path.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\ImPfad\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(r"https://www.google.de/") 
driver.save_screenshot(r"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Kalender.png")
driver.quit()
```

(tested)

But there is an open issue: When the page need **credentials** (login, password), you have still a problem.

Comment: Hi, I wonder if you could explain how I can "add a link to the desktop with a target"? I downloaded Htmlwindow, but don't know how to use it.